# how to check out wordsize on linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libc

As we can see a macro defined in stdint.h or bits/types.h etc.. which is __WORDSIZE. I don't know where to check out whether this macro is defined. Also, is there a way to checkout different size of the basic types without using the sizeof in c. I mean, is there a document exhibits the size of those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on the platform.   First, there are some requirements set by the C standard and/or the POSIX standard if you use UNIX. Things like `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)` or `sizeof(char) == 1`

Then the ABI has the final say.  For example, on linux/freebsd/solaris on x86_64, they use a common ABI: http://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf

3.1.2 in this document has the size for all types for this ABI

Comment: Thanks for you penetrating opinion first, I didn't know the abi confine the data type sizes. I thought datatype sizes are just compiler's chore. Here is a further question, does elf contains any information about what type the variable is defined with? I thought that the elf just contains assembly code in the text part, why does it bother to define the data type sizes? That puzzled me a little bit.

Comment: @dspjm the ABI by definition is not portable. It defines what is the binary interface of a specific platform (OS+hardware architecture). It would be sub-optimal to have an ABI that works on both 32-bit and 64-bit x86 processors. x86_64 has a lot more registers and a compiler generating code that targets the ABI would not be able to use these registers for parameter passing etc (note that some ABI do that for transition purposes, such as sparc v8plus). The ELF header has some information on the target cpu and the target OS but does not define the full ABI